# issue with json decode value stored in mysql

Tags: php, json

I have the following value stored in mysql : `a:3:{i:0;s:2:"35";i:1;s:2:"33";i:2;s:2:"50";}`

when I use

```
 $value= 'a:3:{i:0;s:2:"35";i:1;s:2:"33";i:2;s:2:"50";}'
 $data_array = json_decode($value);
 var_dump($data_array);
```

this returns null.how can I return the values, in this case its 35 33 and 50.

Comment: thats invalid JSON...

Comment: yeah thats unserialize. thanks sorry I missed that

Answer (score 5):

This is not json data. This is serialized data. Use `unserialize` to get an array.

```
$value= 'a:3:{i:0;s:2:"35";i:1;s:2:"33";i:2;s:2:"50";}'
$data_array = unserialize($value);
var_dump($data_array);
```

Answer (score 4):

That is not JSON. It's a serialized array. Use [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/unserialize) instead of json_decode.